# UISearchController disable cancel UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

## The Problem

I am trying to use UISearchController to search for a destination on a map view. I want the UISearchBar to appear in the navigation bar, but I can't seem to make it do so without it showing a cancel button to the right of it:

[image]

This Cancel button has disappeared at times, whilst I'm playing around, but I can't get it to not appear now I have got the search table showing how I want it to:

[image]

I'm sure there must be something small I'm doing ever so slightly wrong, but I can't work out what it is...

## My Code

```
self.resultsViewController = [UITableViewController new];
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsViewController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.searchBar.placeholder = self.stage.title;
self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

self.definesPresentationContext = true;
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;

self.resultsTableView = self.resultsViewController.tableView;
self.resultsTableView.dataSource = self;
self.resultsTableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Hey, I can't answer your question, but currently I am trying to get the same functionallity to work as you just did. I wonder how it is possible to use the UiSearchBar withou a uitableView to create a suggestion list for addresses like you did. Could you provide a few more code examples?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated in light of comments**

`UISearchBar` has a property (see the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/showsCancelButton)) which determines whether the cancel button is displayed:

```
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false;
```

But, as per OP comments, this does not work, because the searchController keeps switching the cancel button back on.  To avoid this, create a subclass of UISearchBar, and override the `setShowsCancelButton` methods:

```
@implementation MySearchBar

-(void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton {
    // Do nothing...
}

-(void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Do nothing....
}

@end
```

To ensure this subclass is used by the searchController, we also need to subclass `UISearchController`, and override the `searchBar` method to return an instance of our subclass.  We also need to ensure that the new searchBar activates the searchController - I've chosen to use the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `textDidChange` for this:

```
@interface MySearchController ()  <UISearchBarDelegate> {
UISearchBar *_searchBar;
}
@end

@implementation MySearchController

-(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (_searchBar == nil) {
        _searchBar = [[MySearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _searchBar.delegate = self;
    }
    return _searchBar;
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if ([searchBar.text length] > 0) {
        self.active = true;
    } else {
        self.active = false;
    }
}
@end
```

Finally, change your code to instantiate this subclass:

```
self.searchController = [[MySearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsViewController];
```

(You will obviously need to import the relevant header files for these subclasses).

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, I believe that pertains to the cancel button within the search bar itself. This search button seems to be controlled by the UISearchController

Comment: @simonthumper I've updated my answer with a solution involving subclassing the searchBar.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was considering, but was hoping there would be an easier solution. I'll probably get a chance to implement this evening, then I'll mark as correct :)

Comment: updateSearchResultsForSearchController stopped working when I used this method.  Any tips?

Comment: @vinnybad Sorry, I had that problem before I implemented the textDidChange method to activate the search controller.  But that fixed it for me.

Comment: @pbasdf I was able to get it working like so: https://gist.github.com/vinnybad/b455e2b6d49f045a73b1

Comment: Thanks for this good anwser, 
I think no need to override -(void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton because it call only the second one, and no need to implement the delegate of the search bar

Answer (score 20):

There is a way easier way...

For iOS 8, and UISearchController, use this delegate method from `UISearchControllerDelegate`:

```
func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
  searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

Don't forget to set yourself as the delegate: `searchController.delegate = self`

Comment: This kind of works, but the Cancel button briefly shows before disappearing.

Comment: @sdsykes Interesting... what version of iOS? It doesn't show at all for me :(

Comment: I'm finding that by doing as suggested above subsequent calls to showsCancelButton work as expected, at least in my case.

Answer (score 13):

Easy solution in **Swift3** - we need to make **CustomSearchBar** without cancel button and then override the corresponding property in new **CustomSearchController**:

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

override func setShowsCancelButton(_ showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
}}

class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {
lazy var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
    [unowned self] in
    let customSearchBar = CustomSearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)
    return customSearchBar
    }()

override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    get {
        return _searchBar
    }
}}
```

In MyViewController I initialize and configure searchController using this new custom subclass:

```
    var videoSearchController: UISearchController = ({
    // Display search results in a separate view controller
    //        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    //        let alternateController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "aTV") as! AlternateTableViewController
    //        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: alternateController)
    let controller = CustomSearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    controller.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. iceland)", comment: "")
    controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    return controller
})()
```

And it works properly and smooth

Comment: Works perfect, also with Swift 4.2 and iOS 11/12.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

**@pbasdf**'s answer works for the most part, but checking the `searchText` length to determine whether the `UISearchController` is active can add more work to the user. The corner case would be if the user hits the **clear** button, or deletes the only character in the search bar. This would set `active` to `NO`, which would automatically call `resignFirstResponder` on the `UISearchBar`. The keyboard would disappear and if the user wants to change the text or enter more text, it would require tapping again on the search bar.

Instead, I only set `active` to `NO` if the search bar is not the first responder (keyboard is not active and displayed), since that is effectively a *cancel* command.

### FJSearchBar

Marking `searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO` doesn't seem to work in **iOS 8**. I haven't tested **iOS 9**.

#### FJSearchBar.h

Empty, but placed here for completeness.

```
@import UIKit;

@interface FJSearchBar : UISearchBar

@end
```

#### FJSearchBar.m

```
#import "FJSearchBar.h"

@implementation FJSearchBar

- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton {
    // do nothing
}

- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // do nothing
}

@end
```

### FJSearchController

Here's where you want to make the real changes. I split the `UISearchBarDelegate` into its own category because, IMHO, the categories make the classes cleaner and easier to maintain. If you want to keep the delegate within the main class interface/implementation, you're more than welcome to do so.

#### FJSearchController.h

```
@import UIKit;

@interface FJSearchController : UISearchController

@end

@interface FJSearchController (UISearchBarDelegate) <UISearchBarDelegate>

@end
```

#### FJSearchController.m

```
#import "FJSearchController.h"
#import "FJSearchBar.h"

@implementation FJSearchController {
@private
    FJSearchBar *_searchBar;
    BOOL _clearedOutside;
}

- (UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (_searchBar == nil) {
        // if you're not hiding the cancel button, simply uncomment the line below and delete the FJSearchBar alloc/init
        // _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        _searchBar = [[FJSearchBar alloc] init];
        _searchBar.delegate = self;
    }
    return _searchBar;
}

@end

@implementation FJSearchController (UISearchBarDelegate)

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // if we cleared from outside then we should not allow any new editing
    BOOL shouldAllowEditing = !_clearedOutside;
    _clearedOutside = NO;
    return shouldAllowEditing;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // hide the keyboard since the user will no longer add any more input
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // the user cleared the search while not in typing mode, so we should deactivate searching
        self.active = NO;
        _clearedOutside = YES;
        return;
    }
    // update the search results
    [self.searchResultsUpdater updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self];
}

@end
```

Some parts to note:

1. I've put the search bar and the `BOOL` as private variables instead of properties because

   - They're more lightweight than private properties.
   - They don't need to be seen or modified by the outside world.
2. We check whether the `searchBar` is the first responder. If it's not, then we actually deactivate the search controller because the text is empty and we're no longer searching. If you **really** want to be sure, you can also ensure that `searchText.length == 0`.
3. `searchBar:textDidChange:` is invoked before `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:`, which is why we handled it in this order.
4. I update the search results every time the text changes, but you may want to move the `[self.searchResultsUpdater updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self];` to `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` if you only want the search performed after the user presses the *Search* button.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the `UISearchBar` to behave as desired without subclassing by calling `setShowsCancelButton` in a couple of `UISearchBarDelegate` methods:

I call it in `textDidChange` and `searchBarCancelButtonClicked`. Here's what my implementation looks like:

```
extension MyViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.characters.isEmpty == false {
            searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)

            // whatever extra stuff you need to do
        } else {
            searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)

            // whatever extra stuff you need to do
        }
        // whatever extra stuff you need to do
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
        // whatever extra stuff you need to do
    }
}
```