# UISearchController searchBar showsCancelButton not being respected

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've added a UISearchController to my application and set it's searchBar to the `titleView` of my `navigationItem`.

This works but I am seeing the cancel button despite having set `showsCancelButton` to `false`.

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsUpdater


    // Configure the searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Find Friends..."
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

[image]

Comment: can you post more of your code.

Comment: Any piece in particular?

Comment: This is finally fixed in iOS 13.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in iOS. The same behavior I've described can be seen in the example project supplied by Apple

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html

The documentation states that the default for this is `NO` but this doesn't seem to be the case. Setting `showsCancelButton` to `NO` seems to have no effect.

I have filed a radar for this and am waiting to hear back.

Comment: did apple get back to you on this issue?  I'm still seeing it happen on 8.4.

Comment: @vinnybad Unfortunately I still have not received a response. I'll be sure to update this if I ever do.

Answer (score 10):

I agree, it seems like a bug.  The problem is that the `searchController` keeps resetting the `showsCancelButton` property of the searchBar.  I found a solution that involves:

1. subclassing `UISearchBar` to ignore `setShowsCancelButton`.
2. to make the searchController use that subclass, you have to subclass `UISearchController`.
3. And then you find that the searchBar is not triggering the search controller's delegate methods, so you have to trigger them separately...

Convoluted, but it seems to do the trick.  You can find the full [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28396967/3985749).

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 12.1.

Answer (score 6):

Easy solution in **Swift3** - we need to make **CustomSearchBar** without cancel button and then override the corresponding property in new **CustomSearchController**:

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

override func setShowsCancelButton(_ showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
}}


class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {

lazy var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
    [unowned self] in
    let customSearchBar = CustomSearchBar(frame: CGRect.zero)
    return customSearchBar
    }()

override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    get {
        return _searchBar
    }
}}
```

In MyViewController I initialize and configure searchController using this new custom subclass:

```
    var mySearchController: UISearchController = ({
    // Display search results in a separate view controller
    //        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    //        let alternateController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "aTV") as! AlternateTableViewController
    //        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: alternateController)
    let controller = CustomSearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    controller.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. iceland)", comment: "")
    controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    return controller
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to correct by putting in a little hack...

Setting the alpha to 0.0 on viewDidLoad because he screen will flash.

Before you ask...willPresentSearchController will not work.

```
extension GDSearchTableViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate {
    func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) { () -> Void in
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            searchController.searchBar.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We wanted the search bar to have no Cancel button initially, but have it appear when the user tapped in the search bar.
Then we wanted the Cancel button to disappear if user tapped Cancel, or otherwise the search bar lost first responder.

What finally worked for me:

On create:

```
searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
```

We use a subclass of UISearchBar and override searchBarShouldBeginEditing thusly:

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar {
    self.showsCancelButton = YES;
    return YES;
}
```

We also override resignFirstReponder (in the UISearchBar subclass) thusly:

```
-(BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    self.showsCancelButton = NO;
    return [super resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also add

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

See if assigning those delegates will help.

Comment: Added but to no avail

Comment: Just to add that "hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation" prevents the search bar from growing when focused

Answer (score 0):

I try to help you man but I'm not sure that I find the real problem.

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setShowsCancelButton:animated:):

```
showsCancelButton
```

> boolean property that indicating whether the cancel button is
>   displayed

But for hide the cancel button maybe you should use:

```
setShowsCancelButton(_:animated:)
```

[image]

I hope that can be helpful.

Comment: The header file for UISearchBar states that the default for `showsCancelButton` is false so presumably I shouldn't have to do anything to hide it.

Comment: mmm just for curiosity have you tried to use the `searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false` in some delegate methods like searchBarTextDidBeginEditing? in that case it works?

Comment: I had a crash for iOS13 until replace calling `showsCancelButton` on `setShowsCancelButton(_:animated:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UISearchBar and override method `layoutSubviews`

```
super.layoutSubviews()
self.showsCancelButton = false
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to set the attribute every time anew when I used the searchcontroller respectively its searchbar. I initialized the searchcontroller lazily without setting the attribute and then did

```
searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
```

every time before search began.
You could do this in the UISearchControllerDelegate methods i.e...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (iOS 10):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to note that this has changed on iOS 13 and quote Apple's documentation on `showsCancelButton`, currently only available on [UISearchBar.h](https://github.com/xybp888/iOS-SDKs/blob/b3fa11b8e9f054cecfa811cb3a7de835f0c08e09/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UISearchBar.h#L54-L59) and not on developer.apple.com

```
/* New behavior on iOS 13.
 If the search bar is owned by a UISearchController, then using the setter
 for this property (as well as -setShowsCancelButton:animated:) will implicitly
 set the UISearchController's automaticallyShowsCancelButton property to NO.
 */
```

`automaticallyShowsCancelButton` has been introduced on iOS 13.0 and should clarify what @pbasdf had already pointed out in his answer: that the buggy behavior is something intrinsic to `UISearchController`.

Answer (score -1):

What about setting it with `[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setShowsCancelButton:animated:

Comment: When are you calling it?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`. It's odd though because the default for showCancelButton is supposed to be `false` so it shouldn't matter