# Hiding Cancel button on search bar in UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to hide the Cancel button of the search bar in the UISearchController, but unfortunately setting the following in viewDidLoad() does not work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchResultsTableController = UITableViewController()
    searchResultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsTableController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchResultsView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

I have also tried using the above code in this delegate method:

```
func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

This approach works but will show the Cancel button briefly before hiding it, which is not ideal. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you elaborate more on your implementation? where did you put searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ended up subclassing both `UISearchBar` and `UISearchController` as suggested:

**CustomSearchBar.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

**CustomSearchController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomSearchController: UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    lazy var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
        [unowned self] in
        let result = CustomSearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)
        result.delegate = self

        return result
    }()

    override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return _searchBar
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution. I'm going to file a radar for this, as one would expect `setShowsCancelButton` would stick throughout the object's lifecycle using the factory object.

Comment: Filed radar # 29859105

Comment: I'm on Swift 3 & iOS 10 and this almost works. Instead, I tried other answer from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42029836/851515) and got a result. 

Instead of overriding `layoutSubviews`, you override `setShowsCancelButton(:animated:)`.

Answer (score 7):

Rejoice! As of iOS 13, there is access to `automaticallyShowsCancelButton` on `UISearchController`. Set it to `false` to hide the cancel button.

Comment: for me the cancel button flies across the screen and then hides.

Answer (score 3):

```
func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
}


func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

In my case all the above solutions dint work. You need to show in  didPresentSearchController and hide it in didDismissSearchController. Earlier I was just hiding in didDismissSearchController which was still showing Cancel button on cancelling.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the Cancel button in search bar delegate methods and set your delegate `searchController.searchBar.delegate=self` `UISearchBarDelegate`

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. The Cancel button still shows up unaffected.

Comment: have u set the delegate properly,check whether delegate func are getting called or not?Its working on ma end

Answer (score 1):

Try subclassing `UISearchBar` and implement:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   self.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
}
```

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396274/uisearchcontroller-disable-cancel-uibarbuttonitem/28396967#28396967) may help you more in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

The same answer as given by @Griffith and @Abhinav but using extension:

```
extension UISearchBar {
    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

This code is from Swift 4.