# UISearchController disable Cancel button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I am setting up a `UISearchController` embedded in a `UNavigationBar` and whatever I try, I cannot seem to disable the Cancel button that appears when attempting to type something inside the `UISearchController` `searchBar`.
So my question is how do you do it?
So far I've tried the below, but neither work.

```
searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false 

searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
```

Comment: What function is that code in? What function is that given function being called from? Sometimes, the issue lies within the trace of what is being called when and from where.

Comment: @bearacuda13 I am using this in the viewDidLoad of my uiViewController

Comment: aight- try throwing that into the other related override methods: viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, etc.

Comment: let me know if any of them work so I can format it in an answer for the rest of the community

Comment: @bearacuda13 none of these will ever work, they have nothing to do with the action trigger to show the cancel button built in the UISearchController class

Comment: Okay. With experience, I've had the right action triggers in the wrong places. Sometimes I call something too late or too early, so the end result is skewed.

Comment: That appears to be part of the solution in this very related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227177/hiding-cancel-button-on-search-bar-in-uisearchcontroller/33263519

Comment: @bearacuda13 I understand. I've tried all of the funcs an none work here

Comment: @bearacuda13 ah, ok, you mean like a subclass of UISearchController?

Comment: Yeah- that might be important

Comment: @bearacuda13  ok, it worked. pretty extensive though for such a minor thing

Answer (score 1):

You can disable cancel button from UISearchBar Delegate method.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: that is an approach, however, in my case it does not work

Comment: @dre_84w934 share your code in brief so we can identify what's actual problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227177/hiding-cancel-button-on-search-bar-in-uisearchcontroller/33263519

Comment: the link above already fixed my problem. thanks for the help

Comment: @dre_84w934, Okay.