# Hide Cancel Button on UISearchController swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, search, ios9, uisearchbar

theres any way to hide the cancel button on UISearchController? [image]

The other behaviour i would like to know if its possible, is when the user press the Cancel Button, to set the text on the UISearchBar.

Thanks

Comment: there is the hide method from the button class ?

Comment: @Lamour " self.searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false) " on init of the UISearchController, doesnt work

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31323242/3985749).

Comment: @pbasdf This works, but the Cancel button briefly shows before disappearing.

Comment: You could try the other answer to that question - though I confess it's a messy solution.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Subclassing both SearchBar and UISearchController

http://stackoverflow.com/a/33263519/927838

Answer (score -2):

Using seachController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated:false) still seems to not do it for this.

Try adding the UISearchBarDelegate to your controller and assign the searchBar's delegate to self. Then you can use the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` to edit its visibility.

```
    import UIKit

    class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var searchController: UISearchController!
    let menuItems: [String] = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let searchResultsController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchResultsViewControllerStoryboardIdentifier") as! SearchResultsTableViewController


        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func searchButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)

        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.menuItems[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could post your code, it will be helpful to see where the issue is. I could able to create a simple app with the above code.. I have updated the code with the complete TableViewController code..