# How to disable cancel button of UISearchController.seachBar when i tap at searchBar?

Tags: ios, swift

i want to disable right cancel button when a tap at search Bar.
Because of using Google Place search i put i should use searchController?.searchBar
I try to disable cancel button at

```
func presentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

but when i tap a searchBar i see how cancel button appear and disappear, thats looks ugly
Please give me advice!

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

    searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
    searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = searchBarPlaceholderText
    searchController?.searchBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607843, green: 0.5490196078, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController?.delegate = self
    searchController?.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent

    definesPresentationContext = true

    mapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    checklocationAuthorizationStatus()

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestLocation()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func presentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom class and subclass UISearchBar and UISearchViewController.
For example:-

```
class CustomizedSearchBar: UISearchBar {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Now Create Object of the **CustomizedSearchBar** and use it within other viewController.

Or you can create a customized **searchViewController** as follows:

```
class CustomizedSearchController: UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    lazy var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
        [unowned self] in
        let result = CustomSearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)
        result.delegate = self

        return result
    }()

    override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return _searchBar
        }
    }
}
```

Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396274/uisearchcontroller-disable-cancel-uibarbuttonitem/42029836#42029836) link for more detail information.